# get hex from color name matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, hex

I know this list of colors that matplotlib support:

https://pythonhosted.org/ete2/reference/reference_svgcolors.html

Is there a programmatic way to convert this names to hex ?

I would like a function that receive the color name and return the hex value of this color.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`matplotlib.colors.cnames` is a dictionary of all of matplotlib's colors and their hex values:

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.colors.cnames["blue"])
  --> u'#0000FF'
```

Comment: What if you are using the shorthand? (Like "g", "b", "r", etc.)