# Convert HTML color name to hex

Tags: python, html, colors, bokeh

Is it possible to convert the HTML color names (i.e. [given on w3cschools](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_groups.asp)) to hex?

For example I want something like:

```py
name_to_hex("Orange")   # would return: #FFA500
```

I found this to be possible with matplotlib in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473660/get-hex-from-color-name-matplotlib).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [webcolors](https://pypi.org/project/webcolors/) module can handle this.

First, install it, e.g.:

```
$ pip install webcolors
```

Once you have it installed, it's pretty straight-forward:

```
>>> import webcolors
>>> webcolors.name_to_hex('Orange')
'#ffa500'
```